# Capturing a Function Name with perl

Tags: regex, perl

I want to create mocking files of some of my header. I want to do this with a Perl script, but I am failing at retrieving the function name.

I need to find a regular expression which converts the whole function name like `public virtual Function` to `Function`, or `private Function*` to `Function`.

Comment: please post the regex you have so far.

Comment: I dont really have a regex yet, only some non working "drafts"

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try

`$FuncName =~ s/\s*\w*\s*\w+(&|\*|(&\*|\*&)?)?\s+((\*&|&\*)|&|\*)?(\w+)((\*&|&\*)?|&|\*)?\s*/$5/;`

this should cut everything beside the name stored in `$FuncName`

```
 # virtual const *foo -> foo 

 # int foo& -> foo 

 # public virtual*& foo*& -> foo
```